# For episodic tasks with an absorbing state, why can't we both have $\gamma=1$ and $T= \infty$ in the definition of the return?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, hyper-parameters, return, discount-factor

For episodic tasks with an absorbing state, why can't $\gamma=1$ and $T= \infty$?

In Sutton and Barto's book, they say that, for episodic tasks with absorbing states that becomes an infinite sequence, then the return  is defined by:

$$G_t=\sum_{k=t+1}^{T}\gamma^{k-t-1}R_k$$

This allows the return to be the same whether the sum is over the first $T$ rewards, where $T$ is the time of termination or over the full infinite sequence, with $T=\infty$ xor $\gamma=1$.

Why can't we have both? I don't see how they can both be set to those parameters. It seems like, if you have an absorbing state, the rewards from terminal onward will just be 0 and not be affected by $\gamma$ or $T$.

Here's the full section of the book on page 57 in the 2nd edition

[image]

I think the reasoning behind this also leads to why for policy evaluation where

$$v_\pi(s)=\sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s',r}p(s',r|s,a)[r+\gamma v_\pi(s')]$$

"Has an existence and uniqueness guarantee only if $\gamma < 1$ or termination is guaranteed under $\pi$"(page 74). This part I'm also a bit confused by, but seems related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T = \infty$ and $\gamma = 1$ cannot be both true at the same time because the return defined in equation 3.11 is supposed to be a *unified* definition of the return for *both* continuing and episodic tasks. In the case of continuing tasks, $T = \infty$ and $\gamma = 1$ cannot be true at the same time, because the return may not be finite in that case (as I think you already understood).

Moreover, note that, in that *specific* example of the book, they assume that the agent ends up in an absorbing state, so this specific sum is finite, no matter whether $T$ is finite or $\infty$, given that, once you enter the absorbing state, you will always get a reward of $0$. Of course, if you discount those specific rewards, the sum will still be finite. However, in general, if you had a different MDP where the absorbing state is not reachable (i.e. the episode never ends), then the return could not be finite.